# ng test for Angular 10 hangs out in gitlab ci

Tags: angular, gitlab-ci, angular10

I'm configuring gitlab ci to run Angular 10 tests.
But they hang out (run longer than 10 minutes).
Why does it happen? How could it be fixed?

Application used has been created by `ng new <app-name>`.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:14.13.1-alpine3.12

before_script:
  - npm install @angular/cli

build:
  stage: build
  script: npm test --watch=false
  only:
    - master
    - merge_requests
```

**Last logs from ci**

```
Compiling @angular/router/testing : es2015 as esm2015
09 10 2020 09:32:21.905:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
09 10 2020 09:32:21.911:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v5.0.9 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
09 10 2020 09:32:21.912:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
09 10 2020 09:32:21.917:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
09 10 2020 09:32:21.919:ERROR [launcher]: No binary for Chrome browser on your platform.
  Please, set "CHROME_BIN" env variable.
09 10 2020 09:32:26.975:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**it does not work and it's normal because In a CI environment like gitlab-ci, there is  no graphical user interface available to run a browser in it** like your do it in your local env, you have to configure **PhantomJS** or other solutions, you have to update your **karma.conf.js**:

```
browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
```

in case you use PhantomJS

```
npm install --save-dev phantomjs-prebuilt karma-phantomjs-launcher
```

add this line to your plugins

```
plugins: [
  require('karma-jasmine'),
  require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),  // add this line 
  require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
  require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
  require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
],
...
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

maybe you need to add some polyfills for that

you can test it locally

```
ng test --watch=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For later on research, I had this issue trying to set up a newly created Angular 15 app and to activate Auto DevOps' Gitlab CI feature. I resolved it with those steps:

1. Generate the karma configuration:

   ng g config karma

> This should generate the karma.conf.js and add its usage to the `angular.json`.
> If it doesn't change your `angular.json`, update it manually and add to `project.<nameofyourproject>.architect.test.options` the following key, value pair: `"karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js"`.

2. Update karma.conf.js to use `ChromeHeadless` and `singleRun`

At the root of the `config.set` parameter, change the `browsers` values from `["Chrome"]` to `["ChromeHeadless"]` and add at the same level a value for the key `singleRun` to true. Giving 2 lines :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    // Other stuffs from angular default configuration...
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Not setting `singleRun` to true, resulted in my case in a never ending Job... Which is logical because by default, it waits to live reload.

3. Install Chrome on the buildpack image running on the Gitlab CI pipeline

From [here](https://github.com/guzmanoj/herokuish-install-chrome), I got the script `install-chrome.sh` that I downloaded and added to the git repository at `bin/install-chrome.sh`. Then I added, in `package.json` in the `scripts` section, this key, value pair: `"heroku-prebuild": "./bin/install-chrome.sh"`.

`heroku-prebuild` will be then called before starting `ng test` and it will have no more trouble finding it.

This is probably not the optimum, but I found this solution is rapid to implement and safe. The only drawback I would say is that it may not leave your deploying image clean... But anyway it may have to be changed, since angular server should not be used as a server, and this is how the deploying image is made by default.